# Get each value after specific words with Regex

Tags: regex

I have the below string and I am trying to get every value after ID and Display Name. I have tried to create a lookup but I could not get it to work and it only grabs the first value while I want to grab all of them.

This was my code to grab the value after DisplayName

```
(?<=\bDisplayName\\\"\=\>\\\")(\w+)
```

When I tried it, it grabs the first value, but only if it is alphabet while most of my text is a mix of Japanese Kanji, Katakana, Hiragana and special characters such as ・.

```
"{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"ContextFreeName\"=>\"本\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"本\", \"Id\"=>\"465392\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"本\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"ジャンル別\", \"Id\"=>\"465610\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"ビジネス・経済\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"ビジネス・経済\", \"Id\"=>\"466282\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"経営学・キャリア・MBA\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"経営学・キャリア・MBA\", \"Id\"=>\"492076\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"経営学・キャリア・MBAの起業・開業\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"起業・開業\", \"Id\"=>\"492058\", \"IsRoot\"=>false}"
```

What I want to achieve from the above string is the following:

- Grab each string after DisplayName

  ex.

  "DisplayName"=>"本" grab 本

  "DisplayName"=>"経営学・キャリア・MBA" grab 経営学・キャリア・MBA
- Grab each integer after Id

  ex.

  "Id"=>"465392" grab 465392

  "Id"=>"4920588" grab 4920588

Is it possible to do this in Regex or should I look for something else than Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**capturing groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) like in

```js
"DisplayName"=>"([^"]*)"
"Id"=>"(\d+)
```

*Details*:

- `"DisplayName"=>"([^"]*)"` - `"DisplayName"=>"` is matched first, then one or more chars other than `"` are captured into Group 1.
- `"Id"=>"(\d+)` - `"Id"=>"` is matched first, then one or more digits are captured into Group 1.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EzYGck):

```py
import re
s = "{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"Ancestor\"=>{\"ContextFreeName\"=>\"本\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"本\", \"Id\"=>\"465392\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"本\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"ジャンル別\", \"Id\"=>\"465610\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"ビジネス・経済\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"ビジネス・経済\", \"Id\"=>\"466282\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"経営学・キャリア・MBA\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"経営学・キャリア・MBA\", \"Id\"=>\"492076\"}, \"ContextFreeName\"=>\"経営学・キャリア・MBAの起業・開業\", \"DisplayName\"=>\"起業・開業\", \"Id\"=>\"492058\", \"IsRoot\"=>false}"
 
print(re.findall(r'"DisplayName"=>"([^"]*)"', s))
# => ['本', 'ジャンル別', 'ビジネス・経済', '経営学・キャリア・MBA', '起業・開業']

print(re.findall(r'"Id"=>"(\d+)', s))
# => ['465392', '465610', '466282', '492076', '492058']
```